# Tkinter buttons not showing up even after using geometry managers

Tags: python, tkinter, geometry

So, Basically i'm tryna display buttons for a student dashboard in a gui that im creating but something seems to be the problem with the code. Its not displaying the buttons at all

```
# Function to display the student dashboard
def show_student_dashboard():
    global student_window
    student_window = tk.Toplevel(main_screen)
    student_window.title("Student Dashboard")
    student_window.attributes('-fullscreen', True) # Set window dimensions

    def resize_image(event):
        new_width  = event.width
        new_height = event.height
        image      = copy_of_image.resize((new_width, new_height))
        photo      = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        label.config(image=photo)
        # Avoid garbage collection
        label.image= photo

    random_images = ["graphics/user-screen.png"]
    random_image  = random.choice(random_images)
    image = Image.open(random_image)
    copy_of_image = image.copy()
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label = Label(student_window, image=photo)
    label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    label.bind('<Configure>', resize_image)

    user_view_text_right = Label(student_window, text="Welcome back\n" + username1 + "!", fg="#ff6c00", bg="#ffffff", font=("Stem-bold", 36, "bold"))
    user_view_text_right.place(relx=0.77, rely=0.20, anchor=CENTER)

    # Buttons for student actions
    browse_button_image = PhotoImage(file="graphics/user-view-course.png")
    browse_button = ttk.Button(student_window, image=browse_button_image, borderwidth=0, bg="#ffffff", command=browse_courses)
    browse_button.place(relx=0.76, rely=0.50, anchor=CENTER)

    enroll_button_image = PhotoImage(file="graphics/user-add-course.png")
    enroll_button = ttk.Button(student_window, image=enroll_button_image, borderwidth=0, bg="#ffffff", command=enroll_courses)
    enroll_button.place(relx=0.76, rely=0.60, anchor=CENTER)

    timetable_button_image = PhotoImage(file="graphics/user-add-course.png")
    timetable_button = ttk.Button(student_window, image=timetable_button_image, borderwidth=0, bg="#ffffff", command=view_timetable)
    timetable_button.place(relx=0.76, rely=0.70, anchor=CENTER)

    announcements_button_image = PhotoImage(file="graphics/user-delete-course")
    announcements_button = ttk.Button(student_window,  image=announcements_button_image, borderwidth=0, bg="#ffffff", command=view_announcements)
    announcements_button.place(relx=0.76, rely=0.80, anchor=CENTER)

    logout_button_image = PhotoImage(file="graphics/logout.png")
    user_logout_button = Button(student_window, image=logout_button_image, borderwidth=0, command=delete_student_dashboard)
    user_logout_button.place(relx=0.76, rely=0.80, anchor=CENTER)

    student_window.mainloop()
```

I'm expecting to see this:

[image: Dashboard with buttons]

But this is how it currently looks like:

[image]

Comment: student_window = tk.Toplevel(main_screen)
NameError: name 'main_screen' is not defined